# Can Logstash generate multiple events from a block of aggregated loglines?

Tags: logstash, aggregate

Can Logstash convert the following block of loglines into 2 separate loglines?

```
2020-05-20 00:06:38,685 [INFO] [45678] Begin Packet [ID:999999 S#123] **** 
2020-05-20 00:06:38,685 [INFO] [45678]      Event 1 of 2 : Sequence:100 SUBID:222222 Code:Working
2020-05-20 00:06:38,685 [INFO] [45678]           Parameter Check = 45
2020-05-20 00:06:38,685 [INFO] [45678]           Parameter Slap = 8080
2020-05-20 00:06:38,685 [INFO] [45678]      Event 2 of 2 : Sequence:101 SUBID:333333 Code:Dancing
2020-05-20 00:06:38,685 [INFO] [45678]           Parameter Poke = 60
2020-05-20 00:06:38,685 [INFO] [45678]           Parameter Stab = 2424
```

Resulting in:

```
2020-05-20 00:06:38,685 id:999999 s:123 event:1 sequence:100 subid:222222 code:Working check:45 slap:8080
2020-05-20 00:06:38,685 id:999999 s:123 event:2 sequence:101 subid:333333 code:Dancing poke:60 stab:2424
```

The timestamp is always unique for this related block of events so I tried using the aggregate filter to combine them. But I didn't see a way to generate 2 events out of the results, or even how to avoid overwriting the results. from the previous event instead of just pushing it.